# Which security method should I use when sending text data to a SQL server?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# desktop application and I need to send text data to a remote SQL Server.
What should I use for security? Web service or socket or another?

Comment: Please provide more information about your scenario, the question is very short and does not really show your requirements.

Comment: Web services and sockets are not security measures. They are communication protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Services and sockets are ways for an application to communicate with SQL server. In it of themselves, they do not provide security.

Now if you are wondering how you should communicate with your SQL server from your applications, that depends on your scenarios. Web Services is what I go with if I need to communicate with SQL through more than one application. For example, if you have your desktop application and, for example, an Android application or a web application.

Now if you are wondering about security, you should be encrypting your data and storing the encrypted data in the SQL server. When you retrieve the data, you should decrypt it. Also, make sure your site runs on HTTPS protocol and not HTTP.

Comment: I think if my application decompiller client computer, my SQL server connection strings are show. I want another connection method my SQL server?

Comment: @user3666417 - No, no. What you do is encrypt your connection string, then store the encrypted connection string in your app.config file.

Comment: Thanks for help, please give me a simple example